# How to get PHP natcasesort to permanently rearrange array positions?

Tags: php, arrays

Looking at the documentation for natcasesort in PHP it sorts the array in a case insensitive way. However after I try to rearrange a two unordered arrays that contain the same letters, and check if they are equivalent it give me false. See below:

```
$ary=array("b", "z", "A", "C", "S");
$ary1=array("A", "z", "b", "S", "C");
natcasesort($ary);
natcasesort($ary1);
print_r($ary);
print_r($ary1);

if ($ary==$ary1) {
  echo "True";  
} else {
  echo "False";
}
```

The results I get are:

```
Array ( [2] => A [0] => b [3] => C [4] => S [1] => z ) 

Array ( [0] => A [2] => b [4] => C [3] => S [1] => z ) 

False
```

This obviously is because it still saves the original position of the letter in the original array. How can I change the original postion displayed in the brackets to change permanently into an increasing count (in this case 0 to 4 in case-insensitive alphabetical order)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_values` to get a new array with new indexes:

```
natcasesort($ary);
natcasesort($ary1);

$ary  = array_values($ary);
$ary1 = array_values($ary1);

if ($ary == $ary1) {
  echo "True";  
} else {
  echo "False";
}
```

Or if you do this a lot build a function:

```
function natcasesortv(&$array) {
    natcasesort($array);    
    $array = array_values($array);
}
```